# How to duplicate a Java GUI Jframe?

Tags: java, user-interface, jframe, jpanel, extend

I have use a Jframe, JPanel made a program which is a countdown Timer. Everything is working good. 
Now, what I want to do is to duplicate it as 10 replicas. That means I want to 10 countdown Timer in one GUI.
Is there any way can do it without write same code 10 times? Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use some design patterns

- Java composite pattern : to create a Timer object which will have all your graphics components of the countdown timer, also it should have their configuration to,
- Java prototype pattern : to clone this timer 10 times

For more info see this [java composite pattern](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2074564/learn-java/a-look-at-the-composite-design-pattern.html), [java prototype pattern](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/prototype_pattern.htm)